# How to get rid of the title bar?

Tags: 14.04, window

As you can see, the top of the window has this long title because of the title of the webpage.

How do I get rid of it?

[image: title bar]

Comment: Under settings -> appearance  there should be a   setting for that. I'm on 16.04  so itw a bit different, it has reveal on hover setting, which is probably what would work best for you. I could make a scrip that will shorten the title if it goes over certain char limit. Let me know of you'd like that

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea, as it will also rid you of the close,minimize,maximize buttons.

Comment: @Serg I don't think the issue is the length as much as the HTML meta characters. Steven hasn't really explained what the problem is.

Comment: You post a screenshot with folders named "Porno" and "Hentai" here. I guess, you got it all figured out. ;-)

Comment: @mikewhatever i don't think you understand the question correctly. OP wants to get rid of the text, not the titlebar itself

Comment: @UTF-8 and how does this relate to the question ? it's their desktop and they can have whatever folders they want. There's no explicitly displayed images either, just folder titles

Comment: @Serg The title is "How to get rid of the title bar?". I am pretty sure I know what that means. :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever let's wait for OP to explain themselves, but I think they just wanna get rid of text.

Comment: @Serg I just wanted to make him aware of that. After all, he probably uses his real name as his username and has a picture of himself as his avatar. There are a lot of prude people and they might not favor finding something like that about someone if they google their name. Furthermore, I just wikipediad "hentai". I was under the impression that's that tentacle stuff. Apparently, it's not necessarily that.